# PHP: How to find multiple needles in the haystack

Tags: php, strpos

I am retrieving a filename from email and want to check if filename contains an audio file extension (like .mp3 .mp4 .ogg .wav ...)

Looking for a function like str_list_pos($haystack,'.mp3|.mp4|.ogg|.wav');

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given a string containing a file extension then check if it is found in the literal lists of file extensions that you provide. The 'stripos' function is useful for this...

```
$fextFound = stripos('.mp3|.mp4|.ogg|.wav|', $fileExtension .'|') !== false;
```

Note: every extension must have the separator including the last as we have to find an exact match.

as a function:

```
function validFileExtension($fileExtension, $validExtensions =  '.mp3|.mp4|.ogg|.wav|')
{
    return stripos($validExtensions, $fileExtension . '|') !== false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expressions](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) support the OR operator |, loop through the string list and use [Preg match](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to check for a regular expression match.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like this:

```
function match_file_extensions($file, $extensions = array()) {
    return !!preg_match('#^.*('.implode('|', $extensions).')$#', trim($file));
}
```

And the usage:

```
if(match_file_extensions('test.mp3', ['mp3', 'wav', 'avi'])){
    echo 'media file extension found';
}
```

It basically creates a simple regular expression, which matches any string, that ends with any of the given strings, then compares the given string against it.